Jetpack compose. How to create collapsing composable?
I need to implement partially collapsed layout in jetpack compose. When I scroll down the list, I want the top layout to partially collapse, and when I scroll to the top of the list, I want the expanded layout to show again. The behavior is similar to collapsing toolbar, but I don't need collapsing toolbar I need collapsing custom composable.

I took the following solution as a basis: https://github.com/germainkevinbusiness/CollapsingTopBarCompose/tree/master
Here is my code:
@Composable
private fun CollapsingLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    collapsedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    expandedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    scrollBehavior: CollapsingTopBarScrollBehavior,
) = with(scrollBehavior) {

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(currentTopBarHeight)
            .verticalScroll(topBarVerticalScrollState.invoke()),
        color = Color.Unspecified,
        contentColor = Color.Unspecified,
        elevation = 0.dp,
    ) {
        Box {

            // Display expanded content
            expandedContent(Modifier
                .alpha(expandedColumnAlpha.invoke().value)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(currentTopBarHeight))

            // Collapsed content with AnimatedVisibility for smooth transition
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = collapsedTitleAlpha.invoke().value in 0F..1F,
                enter = fadeIn(initialAlpha = collapsedTitleAlpha.invoke().value),
                exit = fadeOut()
            ) {
                collapsedContent(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(scrollBehavior.collapsedTopBarHeight)
                        .align(Alignment.BottomStart),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem is that this code needs to know the height of expanded and collapsed content in advance, but I can't set this height in advance because the height of expanded block can be dynamic. So I'm confused. Please help me to solve this problem.
P.S. partially collapsed composable should stay fixed at the top and not scroll with list.
P.S2. A partially collapsed composable may contain smaller text, and components within that composable may be positioned differently than in an expanded composable.

Should the "Some Text" Composable also scroll with the list like a regular list item, or should it stay fixed at the top?

@BenjyTec, partially collapsed "Some Text" should stay fixed at the top and not scroll with the list

Thanks for the clarification. I added an answer below, is this is what you are looking for?

I am adding another answer to address the extended requirements.
If you need a crossfade animation to allow animating between completely different Composables, try the following code:
@Composable
fun CollapsingLayoutDemo() {

    CollapsingLayout(
        expandedContent = { modifier ->
            Text(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                text = "EXPANDED\nEXPANDED\nEXPANDED\nEXPANDED\nEXPANDED\nEXPANDED"
            )
        },
        collapsedContent = { modifier ->
            Text(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                text = "COLLAPSE\nCOLLAPSE\nCOLLAPSE")
        }
    ) { modifier ->
        LazyColumn() {
            items(50) {
                Card(
                    modifier = modifier.padding(4.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(8.dp),
                        text = "ITEM $it"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CollapsingLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    expandedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    collapsedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit
) {

    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    var currentHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var maxHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }
    var minHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }
    val animationProgress by remember(currentHeight) { mutableFloatStateOf((currentHeight-minHeight) / (maxHeight-minHeight)) }
    Log.d("Collapsible", "$animationProgress")

    LaunchedEffect(maxHeight) {
        if (currentHeight == 0f) {
            currentHeight = maxHeight  // initially expand it
        }
    }

    val nestedScrollConnection = object : NestedScrollConnection {

        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            if (currentHeight != minHeight && available.y < 0) {
                currentHeight = (currentHeight + available.y).coerceAtLeast(minHeight)
                return available
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }

        override fun onPostScroll(
            consumed: Offset,
            available: Offset,
            source: NestedScrollSource
        ): Offset {
            if (currentHeight != maxHeight && available.y > 0) {
                currentHeight = (currentHeight + available.y).coerceAtMost(maxHeight)
                return available
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).then(
                    if (currentHeight != 0f) {
                        Modifier
                            .height(with(localDensity) { currentHeight.toDp() } )
                            .clipToBounds()
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                )
            ) {
                expandedContent(
                    Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        if (maxHeight == -1f) {
                            maxHeight = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                        }
                    }.alpha(animationProgress)
                )
                collapsedContent(
                    Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        if (minHeight == -1f) {
                            minHeight = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                        }
                    }.alpha(1 - animationProgress)
                )
            }
        }

        content(Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
}

Output:


I would approach this without AnimatedVisibility, instead clip the height of the CollapsingLayout using a NestedScrollConnection.
Please try the following code:
@Composable
fun CollapsingLayoutDemo() {

    CollapsingLayout(
        expandedContent = { modifier ->
            Text(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                text = "HEADER\nHEADER\nHEADER"
            )
        },
        collapsedContent = { modifier ->
            Text(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                text = "COLLAPSE\nCOLLAPSE\nCOLLAPSE")
        }
    ) { modifier ->
        LazyColumn() {
            items(50) {
                Card(
                    modifier = modifier.padding(4.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(8.dp),
                        text = "ITEM $it"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CollapsingLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    expandedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    collapsedContent: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit
) {

    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    var currentHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var maxHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }
    var minHeight by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = object : NestedScrollConnection {

        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            if (currentHeight != minHeight && available.y < 0) {
                currentHeight = (currentHeight + available.y).coerceAtLeast(minHeight)
                return available
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }

        override fun onPostScroll(
            consumed: Offset,
            available: Offset,
            source: NestedScrollSource
        ): Offset {
            if (currentHeight != maxHeight && available.y > 0) {
                currentHeight = (currentHeight + available.y).coerceAtMost(maxHeight)
                return available
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).then(
                    if (maxHeight == -1f) {
                        Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                                currentHeight = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                                maxHeight = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                            }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                            .height(with(localDensity) { currentHeight.toDp() } )
                            .clipToBounds()
                    }
                )
            ) {
                expandedContent(
                    Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        if (minHeight == -1f) {
                            minHeight = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                        }
                    }
                )
                collapsedContent(
                    Modifier
                )
            }
        }

        content(Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
}

Output:

Note:
In order to properly catch all scroll events, the scrollable content must be inside of the CollapsingLayout. I added a content parameter that holds any Composable displayed below the sticky Composable at the top.

Thanks for such a detailed answer! I'm not sure that simply clip the height would be a good solution for me, since the collapsed version of the composable may have a smaller font size for text elements. That is, a partially collapsed composable does not necessarily have to match the top of the expanded composable, it may even change the layout of the components to a more compact one.

@testivanivan Okay sorry, that was not depicted in the mockup. However, I think with AnimatedVisibility you will not get a great user experience, as the "amount of scrolling" is not taken into consideration - either it is collapsed or it is expanded. I will do some research if there is another animation in Compose that allows an exact value of how much the transition should progress.

You are right, there was not enough information in my question, I updated the question. Thank you for your interest

I added another answer below. I will leave this answer for completeness, in case anyone is looking for behavior like this.
