Nested Scrolling with collapsible header not working
I have been trying to collapse/expand a header when lazy column list scroll up or down using nested scrolling. I have been using following code
@Composable
fun ScrollableScreenWithCollapsibleHeader() {
val headerHeight = 150.dp // Initial header height
var headerOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            val newOffset = headerOffset + delta
            headerOffset = newOffset.coerceIn(0f, headerHeight.value)
            return Offset(x = 0f, y = newOffset - headerOffset)
        }
    }
}

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
            .padding(top = headerHeight) // Add padding for the header
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            Text(item, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        }
    }

    MyHeader(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(headerHeight)
            .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = headerOffset.toInt()) }
    )
}


@Composable
fun MyHeader(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
// ... Your header content here ...
Box(modifier = modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
    Text("Header", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
}
}

But list is not even scrolling, other than collapsing or expanding header. What i am doing wrong

Not sure it will fix your problem completely, but the nestedScroll modifier should be applied to the parent of the scrolling content - the Box in your case. So you should start with that.

There are a few issues in your code:

The nestedScroll Modifier must be applied to the parent Composable that contains both Composables that should be affected by the scrolling
You are using coerceIn with 0 as lower bound. But if you want to vertically offset the MyHeader Composable, then the headerOffset needs to become negative. Your code prevents that.
The onPreScroll function must return the Offset which was consumed. Your current implementation returns the Offset that was not consumed.
Using an offset Modifier is an appropriate way to shift a Composable into a direction, but the problem is that the space where the Composable originally was placed remains reserved for that Composable. So your LazyColumn will not be able to use the space that is reserved for the MyHeader, even when you offset it. So I would suggest to modify the height instead of using offset.
Be careful not to mix dp and px units. The height Modifier takes dp, the offset Modifier takes px.
Instead of using a Box and setting a padding on the LazyColumn, you should use a Column and a weight.

I would suggest the following refactored code:
@Composable
fun ScrollableScreenWithCollapsibleHeader() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    var minHeaderHeightPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }
    var maxHeaderHeightPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(-1f) }
    var currentHeaderHeightPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newHeaderHeightPx = currentHeaderHeightPx + delta
                currentHeaderHeightPx = newHeaderHeightPx.coerceIn(minHeaderHeightPx, maxHeaderHeightPx)
                val unconsumedPx = newHeaderHeightPx - currentHeaderHeightPx
                return Offset(x = 0f, y = delta - unconsumedPx)
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        MyHeader(
            modifier = if (maxHeaderHeightPx == -1f) {
                Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    currentHeaderHeightPx = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                    maxHeaderHeightPx = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                    minHeaderHeightPx = maxHeaderHeightPx / 2  // set min height to 50% of full height
                }
            } else {
                Modifier
                    .height(currentHeaderHeightPx.toInt().pxToDp(density))
                    .clipToBounds()
            }
        )
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(50) { item ->
                Text("Item $item", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MyHeader(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true, align = Alignment.Bottom),
    ) {
        Text("Header A", fontSize = 35.sp)
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text("Header B", fontSize = 35.sp)
    }
}

fun Int.pxToDp(density: Density) = with(density) { this@pxToDp.toDp() }

This code does the following things:

Initially, when there is no maxHeaderHeightPx set, we use the onGloballyPositioned Modifier to find out which height the expanded MyHeader has after it was composed initially. Then we set currentHeaderHeightPx and maxHeaderHeightPx to that height of MyHeader, and define that the minHeaderHeight should be half of it.
Then, once maxHeaderHeightPx is initialized, we set the height of the MyHeader to currentHeaderHeightPx.
Whenever we scroll, and the currentHeaderHeightPx is somewhere between minHeaderHeightPx and maxHeaderHeightPx, we update the currentHeaderHeightPx in the onPreScroll function and return the amount of scroll that we consumed.
If we don't consume any scroll because MyHeader is already fully collapsed or expanded, all scroll will be passed on and consumed by the LazyColumn.
When we apply the height Modifier on MyHeader, the MyHeader would be clipped starting from the bottom. This would give a wrong visual indication. Instead, we want MyHeader to be clipped beginning from the top, so that it looks like it is shifting out of the screen. To achieve this, we use wrapContentHeight with unbounded = true and Alignment.Bottom. Then, when the MyHeader content height exceeds its container, it is allowed to draw out of bounds and does align the content to the bottom while doing so.

Output:


This works fine. That helps me a lot. Just one more question, what if want to scroll the header up but up to certain height i.e when header height remains say 50.dp it stop scrolling up and list scrolling should work now.

Happy to help @RajeevKumar! Feel free to mark this answer as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer. To only collapse the header to a certain height, have a look at my answers at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79176917/jetpack-compose-how-to-create-collapsing-composable/79177926#79177926

I will mark it as answer for sure. But i don't want collapsible header or adjusting height. I want header to be scroll up to certain height, then list start scroll.

@RajeevKumar I just updated this answer to also include a minHeaderHeightPx variable where you can set to which minimal height the header should collapse. Do you want the header to partially move out of the screen at the top when scrolling up? This might be tricky, as I wrote, you can't use the offset Modifier to achieve this.

Yes exactly, i want header to scroll up at the top up to certain height.

I have tried no of ways but no luck so far. I have set dynamic offset for child column also but it leaves white space from bottom of the app. Is there a way we can fill the space left by setting -ve offset ?

See my edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Thanks for all the efforts. It is quite close to my requirements.

can you please elaborate, how this code works. Could not get what Modifier.onGloballyPositioned is actually doing. It would helpful for other users too to understand your code as well.

@RajeevKumar You're right. I added explanations, see my edited answer.
